# Проблемы с областью видимости переменных в процесса python (multiprocessing)

Tags: python, область-видимости

Вот такой код по идее должен запустить процесс, изменить через блокировку глобальную переменную glob(должно стать 20). Но по факту переменная glob в итоге не меняется, как будто выходя из функции не сохраняется значение:

```
glob = 10
def printer(item, lock):
    global glob
    lock.acquire()
    try:
        glob = glob + 10
        print('proc {0} var {1}'.format(item,glob))
    finally:
        lock.release()


lock = Lock()

for i in range(1):
    p = Process(target=printer, args=(i, lock))
    p.start()
    p.join()

print(glob)
```

Comment: В приведённом коде нет запуска потоков.

Comment: я имел ввиду процесс

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11056415 - если я правильно понял, при создании нового процесса при помощи multiprocessing состояние у дочернего процесса своё (новое), а в родителе - остаётся старое. Соответственно, все действия дочернего процесса на состояние старого не влияют

Comment: @AlexNasov очевидно, у каждого процесса своя память. Это всё равно, что открыть два калькулятора, сложить в одном 2 + 2, а потом удивиться, что во втором 4 не отображается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того чтоб передать состояние от одного процесса к другому используйте [multiprocessing.Manager, multiprocessing.Value или multiprocessing.Array](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes)

Просто объявите переменную до запуска потомков таким образом и всё заработает через sharedmem.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value
glob = Value('i',10)

def printer(item, num):
    num += 10
    print('proc {0} var {1}'.format(item, num))

for i in range(2):
    p = Process(target=printer, args=(i, glob))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Также [там есть встроенный Lock](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value)

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value
glob = Value('i', 10, lock=True)
```

Comment: попробую, не знал про такое. Спасибо.